# Curved scrollbars on WearableRecyclerView

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to display curved scrollbars on WearableRecyclerView but it's not working, here's what I have:

In the main activity I have this:

```
    <android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout>
```

I'm replacing the homeContainer with a fragment that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ScheduleFragment"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right">

    <android.support.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/vesselsWRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissFrameLayout>
```

I need the fragment to be swipeable that's why the wearablerecycler is wrapped inside the swipedismiss. The row for the recycler looks like this:

```
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/terminalRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:boxedEdges="left|right">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vesselPicture"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/vessel"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Everything is working fine: I can swipe the fragment, the list is boxed, and the scrollbar is on the right edge of the screen but it isn't curved. I appreciate any help in the matter.

[Screenshot of the list with the scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK7A9.png)

Comment: Try using [`setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView#setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(boolean)). Also another [interesting article](https://www.deviantdev.com/journal/android-wear-scrollable-boxinsetlayout) that I think could help you with. From here the solution is scrapping the [`BoxInsetLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/BoxInsetLayout). Give it a try.

Comment: Im only using [BoxInsetLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/BoxInsetLayout) inside of each row, the [WearableRecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView) is able to scroll, the problem is with the shape of the scrollbars, also the [setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/BoxInsetLayout) its for enabling circular gestures so the user can scroll making a circular gesture over the list, but i appreciate the help, thanks.